# get the values of firebase firestore value

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I wanted to get the values of firebase firestore value but I keep on getting errors, is there a way to retrieve the values without adding a "" ?

```
DocumentReference documentReference = fStore.collection("Users").document(UserID);
    documentReference.addSnapshotListener(this, new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
            assert value != null;
            mBankBalance.setText(""+ value.getDouble("Balance"));

        }
    });
```

the `mBankBalance.setText(""+value.getDouble("Balance"))` line is getting an error whenever i delete the double quotes. Is there a way to get the values only?

Comment: see this ->  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#java_4

Comment: can you atleast explain why i keep getting errors or is it possible to use just value.getDouble()?

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question. Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the value fine already, but you can't set a `Double` value to a text view.

You can most easily see this if you split the code over a few more lines:

```
DocumentReference documentReference = fStore.collection("Users").document(UserID);

documentReference.addSnapshotListener(this, new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
        assert value != null;
        Double balance = value.getDouble("Balance"));
        mBankBalance.setText(balance);
    }
});
```

With this code, you'll an error on `mBankBalance.setText(balance);`, while `Double balance = value.getDouble("Balance"));` actually works fine.

The reason is that `setText()` expects a string value only, and it won't convert your `Double` to a string. That's what the `"" +`  in your original code does, and the same would work above:

```
mBankBalance.setText("" + balance);
```

If you (rightfully) don't like having an empty string like that in your code, you can also use this more explicit conversion:

```
mBankBalance.setText(String.valueOf(balance));
```

Comment: thanks it worked fine, thankyou very much!

Comment: Hey @Jm25E. Anything else needed here? If not, an upvote and possibly accept would be appreciated.

Comment: uhh the site says that Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.